# Google Maps iOS SDK - Running Samples

Tags: ios, google-maps

I setup the 'SDKDemos' when I run it i get the following.
My API key is correct and my bundle ID matches the values in the developer console along with the API key. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.
I get the same in my simulator or on the iPhone.
thanks in advance

Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to ENABLE API - that's not included in the steps - in the dev console